# Does anyone know a way to suppress No Instances Available via batch file using WMIC?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Working in Windows 10 and Server 2016. The syntax works just fine for finding the version of the installed product and outputting it. But if the product is not installed I do not want the 'No Instance(s) Available.' to show. I believe there is a 2>nul or 2>&1 option to suppress this message from appearing in the command box but I don't know where to put it. Please let me know if you have any ideas where this should go or what I'm missing? TIA!! See syntax below...

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
 'wmic product where "name='Application Name'" get version /format:list'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "appver=%%A"
```

Comment: Send the message, which is in the error stream, to the NUL device: `'%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Product Where "Name='Application Name'" Get Version /Format:List 2^>NUL'`.

Comment: Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on __FOR__ command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command __FOR__ which executes the embedded `wmic` command line in a separate command process started in background with `cmd.exe /c` and the command line appended as arguments.

Comment: BTW: There is no need to enable delayed expansion for the posted code.